# Time measuring in month with Arduino

Tags: arduino

Is there a way to get the month with an Arduino?

I'm building my own [Garduino](http://blog.makezine.com/projects/make-18/garduino-geek-gardening/), for an indoor garden, and I need to know the month since I've start to change the light period.

Comment: You would either need to insure continued power and a way to set the clock, or else you might want to look at using a real time clock module with its own backup battery.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to check the tools available on the Arduino offical web page. Check out the library [DateTime](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/DateTime).